# iOS - Submission to app store - Metadata

Tags: ios, screenshot, iad

In my iOS application, I integrated iAds.
When running the app on iPhone to take screen shots its showing empty box which is as expected 
But iOS app store guidelines says that we cannot use those screen shots to upload to app store account during upload.
How can i make my screen shots without having the empty boxes for iAds.... do I've to remove iAds and take screen shots or do I have to edit my screen shots manually in photoshop or something.?

Comment: I don't know much about iAds, but I'm pretty sure, if it's like most other content, you can just set the add to hidden with something like `iad.hidden = true;`, then take your screenshots, then remove it. Again, just a guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes Apple will most definitely reject your app. One way of overcoming this is just set the device to airplane mode to hide them. I’ve never personally submitted an app with iAd before but give it a try.